# why does python concatenate paths

Tags: python, path, windows-8

[image]

I am trying to ad a path to my PYTHONPATH var so it will grab a library

if you look at the output of sys.path you'll notice that two paths are joined/concatenated.

- the simpleauth path
- and the appengine path

why does python concatenate the appengine path with the current path I'm in?

I'm trying to add appengine to the python path to a windows 8 machine and I'm about out of ideas.

I have a

- .pth file in the "site-packages" folder with the wanted path to be added enclosed in quotes and forward slashes escaped

  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine"
- PYTHONPATH system variable with the wanted path to be added enclosed in quotes

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine"
- PYTHONPATH user variable same as system variable

Comment: Add it via My Desktop SETTINGS or what ever Win8 equivalent is. The way you do it is clearly not working. And Win8 should have GUI for that.

Comment: don't quite understand the question? What path is missing from your `sys.path` call? and where is this path defined?

Comment: if you look at the output you'll see that the simpleauth folder is munged with the appengine folder. why? no clue.

Comment: "Munge" is obscure and unclear. For those who didn't understand the question: The issue is that two paths are joined together; `...\\simpleauth-master\\"C:\\Program Files...` has no comma in between. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Chris, what makes you think Python is doing the munging? Maybe your `.pth` file, `PYTHONPATH` system variable, and `PYTHONPATH` user variable are all perfectly fine, but you haven't shown them to us, or even told us that you checked them. (For example, does `echo %PYTHONPATH%` in a cmd shell gives the same result as `sys.path` in Python?) It's much more likely that you've done something wrong in your setup than that Python has an error that nobody has ever noticed creating `sys.path`, but you're assuming it must be the latter, and demanding the answer to a question that probably has none.

Comment: @abarnet you're comment is constructive in it's approach and totally reasonable, to attack the question doesn't solve the issue. I made two different approaches to adding the path to PYTHONPATH that were unsuccessful AND created an anomaly by concatenating paths. My question was "why does it do this?" or "what would cause the path creation to do this?" which are legitimate questions that I believe would aid the community in understanding how this could happen and how to avoid in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the two environment variables

restarted the machine

recreated the .pth file

added the path:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine
```

(WITH the ESCAPES for the forward slashes and WITHOUT any QUOTES)

even though the path has spaces in it, as long as the path is on it's own line it is captured correctly, but adding the quotes somehow caused the sys.path creation to concatenate the value with the previous path value?? don't know just that it did.

that fixed it.

Comment: By not using escape character on your `\\` you made it escape the closing quote instead. This is why it was showing up as one long string.